# Zurb Foundation + Compass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I've used Zurb Foundation Framework to build my website, now I'd want to use ["Sticky footer"](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/layout/sticky-footer/) of Compass but I cannot include Compass

```
gem 'zurb-foundation', :git => "https://github.com/zurb/foundation.git"
gem "compass"
```

**Application.scss**

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "foundation_and_overrides";
@import "buttons";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "page";
@import "pagination";
@import "footer";
@import "app";
```

**footer.css.sass**

```
@import compass/reset.scss
@import compass/layout.scss

+sticky-footer(72px, "#layout", "#layout_footer", "#footer")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like Rails4 -- compass is not yet ready for Rails4.

You could try your luck with version 2.0.alpha.0  on compass-rails -- it's been released for about 4 days now.

```
gem 'compass-rails', '2.0.alpha.0'
```

Comment: See also the discussion here, Foundation had a brief hiccup with Compass breaking on Bower update: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/18624-foundation-5-and-compass-10